# Retroactively get original column:error using a source map

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, source-maps

When running our Selenium tests on our webapp we get access to the console logs in case the javascript crashes, which typically looks like this:

```
09:27:09.540 [main] ERROR gui.rule.ScreenshotRule - Chrome console: SEVERE https://localhost:56962/bundle.js 94:74996 TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Now, `bundle.js 94:74996` isn't all that useful on its own (though I can still use `vim` with some success), but we do produce source maps with the bundle build (which Chrome for some reason chooses not to use in the app crashes), which would be quite useful here. Is there a way of retroactively convert `LINE:COLUMN` pairs using the original source map?

Comment: I think I could use [stacktrace-gps](https://www.stacktracejs.com/#!/docs/stacktrace-gps) to make a util that when given `bundle.js`, `bundle.js.map` and a `location` would print this out using Puppeteer. It would be great if this already existed, though :p

Comment: Ha, not the first to think these thoughts: https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/07/07/resolving-minified-production-stacktrace.html

Comment: Done! https://github.com/fatso83/stacktrace-cli

Answer (score 1):

I ended up hacking together [the tool I wanted](https://github.com/fatso83/stacktrace-cli): `stacktrace-cli`.

Now you can do this:

```
npx @fatso83/stacktrace-cli app-bundle.js app-bundle.js.map 129:600036
```

Resulting in this output:

```
{
    "columnNumber": 56,
    "lineNumber": 78,
    "fileName": "webpack:///src/store/entity/entity-reducer.js",
    "functionName": "getEntitysById"
}
{
    "columnNumber": 56,
    "lineNumber": 78,
    "fileName": "webpack:///src/store/entity/entity-reducer.js",
    "functionName": "map"
}
```

Comment: Your answer is outdated, the * syntax no longer works. You have to specify both files, js and map, one after another.

Comment: It's not outdated, but clearly _shell dependant_ (good to note!). The star is a glob pattern, which may or may not be supported by your current shell, but in Bash this would expand to both files alphabetically, first the js and then the map, if they are called foo.js and foo.js.map. Example: 
`$ echo foo.js* # prints "foo.js foo.js.map"`

Comment: Updated the answer to list the files explicitly. Thanks for the notice!

Comment: Yeah I tried this in cmd. Thanks for updating.